# Add a moving marker to the map, openlayers with angular

Tags: angular, openlayers

I would like to add a marker/pinpoint to the map from OpenLayers in combination with Angular8
The following codes gives me a map:

```
export class SimulatieComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  veluwe = [5.8776, 52.1469]; 
  veluweWeb = fromLonLat(this.veluwe);

  map: Map;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: this.veluweWeb,
        zoom: 7
      }),
      controls: defaultControls().extend([
        new ZoomToExtent({
          extent: [
            813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122,
            848966.9639063801, 5936863.986909639
          ]
```

How can I add a marker/pinpoint to the map that's moving from a startpoint to an endpoint?

```
In ex : start a A, 324324 324234 move to B 254653, 435345
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is a path, usually represented as a line or an array of points. Possible but not neccesary, the first point of the line is your start point, and the last point of the line is your end point.

After you have a path you need a mechanism to handle time and render your mark on the path. You can use JavaScript `setInterval` function to create events at X milisecond in witch you will update the mark coordinats to the next point in the line.

Another approach could be, using the render of the map as interval events. OL have a very good example using this approach [OL Examples - Marker Animation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ol-ext ol/featureAnimation/Path to animate a feature along a path.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.featureanimation.path.html

Comment: Is there any documatation or tutorial on this?